# Ps4 controller problems

Tags: ps4, controllers

I've brought 2 New controller and both do the same the white light flashes but will not turn on, I'm assuming they are holding power as they are both New and genuine and the light flashes. 
I'm not a computer person and it probably something silly but would appreciate some advise for my son.
Thanks in advance
Gav

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to connect your controller directly to the PS4 using a usb cable. Once connected, you simply press the Playstation button, and the controllers should be connected, even when disconnecting the cable.

If not, hold down share and the Playstation button to enter controller pairing mode, and add them from your Playstation.